# High voltage electron gun

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

In the figure we see a typical electron gun, if the anode is at a positive potential, Why don't electrons collide with the anode in an electron gun?

Another question, if the potential of the anode is high enough to create an electric arc with the cathode, the path of the electrons will be as shown in the image? Or will the electrons go directly to the anode?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design of electron gun would a bit crude because modern ones uses coil to reduce the amount of deflected electrons which hit the anode, also you are right that much of the electrons hits the anode though the specific use of electron guns generally necessitate the electrons that can pass through the hole at anode. Also for the second question electron gun works in vacuum so, at those conditions plasma builds up and you can't see a spark at certain points instead plasma acts as a gas in between anode and cathode so as a hole in the balloon electrons escape from the hole of the anode.

Answer (score 0):

I must recommend you to go through your notes again. If am getting you right, you are saying electrons might not collide with the anode if the is a high voltage difference. Well you are wrong. Electrons do collide but just a little of them pass through the tiny hole on the anode. And just keep in mind the image you have the is a better approximate as to how the electrons will travel at any positive potential difference.